# JMeter with Selenium WebDriver Sampler actually overload the overload PC

Tags: jmeter

I run test in Jmeter with Selenium WebDriver Sampler
on Linux X86  and java SDK 11 
The test run with 50 users.
I run it from the command line with non Gui mode and with Chrome headless mode.

but after 5 minutes the CPU going up to 100% and the memory almost full (8G).

What can I do to improve it?, I need run the test with 200 users and up.

Thanks,
Izik

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting too much from your machine.

Although there are no specific RAM requirements defined at the [Chrome System Requirements page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en), on my machine a **single** Chrome instance with a single tab in ["porno" mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) consumes almost 1GB of RAM. And this is given http://example.com page open, not modern web application with tons of JavaScript

[image]

I bet if you run the following command on your machine - you will get at least 3GB

```
(Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum
```

As per [WebDriver Sampler tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Introduction)

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So my expectation is that you should be conducting the load using HTTP Request samplers and forget about using real browsers (or use 1 instance to collect client-side performance metrics). Just consider following recommendations from [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article to ensure that protocol-based JMeter test has the same network footprint as real browser produces.

---

If you **have to** use real browsers for performance testing you won't be able to launch 200 browser instances on a machine with 8GB of RAM, you will have to find another 30-40 machines of this specifications and go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, Since you are using Selenium it will use the JVM and browser which will consume a lot of memory. I would suggest you to distribute the test in multiple machine if you are going the Selenium route for load testing. This way you will be able to load test for more more number of users.
The best would be to stick to HHTP sampler as suggested above. You could also record and make necessary changes.